# I can't timestamp my .apk

Tags: android, timestamp, apk, signing, jarsigner

I'm trying to sign an .apk to export it on the android store, 
but any how I try to sign it with a timestamp server, 
I fail making it works: "Certificate expires before the actual date"...
What i have tried:

`Jarsigner -tsa http://timestamp.digitcert.com -keystore ... x.apk <alias>`

I don't understand how the timestamp servers are used to sign things, and i don't find information about it.

How can I use the timestamp server to sign my apk ?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp URL is wrong. Its `http://timestamp.digicert.com` and not `http://timestamp.digitcert.com`.